# how to define a model so it's available for rules UI?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I created a model, and whe i try to create a rule i allways recieve this message:

"Note: No model has been defined.
Tip: You will want to import or define a model for this user interface to work !"

any ideas?
TNX

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are missing an import.

In the file where you have the rule do:

```
import org.hello.MyModel;
```